# Alternative to nested select statement

Tags: performance, select, nested

I'd like to avoid using a nested selected statement if I can (I suspect I'm going to run into performance issues). I'm trying to get a total for each type of transaction from a financial transaction table. I'm guessing I could use multiple selects from the same table BUT my 'BFWD' figures return their results by `"bil_yer + 1"` (not just the raw `bil_yer`). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT bil_yer,
    acc_num,
    ubsgch_key_num,
    sum(bfw_arr) AS bfw_arr,
    sum(bfw_int) AS bfw_int,
    sum(ytd_chg) AS ytd_chg,
    sum(ytd_och) AS ytd_och
FROM (
    -- BFWD Charges
    SELECT src_bil_yer + 1 AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        src_trn_amt AS bfw_arr,
        0 AS bfw_int,
        0 AS ytd_chg,
        0 AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran
    WHERE src_trn_cde <> 2601

    UNION ALL -- BFWD Interest
    SELECT src_bil_yer + 1 AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        0 AS bfw_arr,
        src_trn_amt AS bfw_int,
        0 AS ytd_chg,
        0 AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran
    WHERE src_trn_cde = 2601

    UNION ALL -- YTD Current Charges - Raised in the current year but NOT past due
    SELECT src_bil_yer AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        0 AS bfw_arr,
        0 AS bfw_int,
        src_trn_amt AS ytd_chg,
        0 AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran
    WHERE src_trn_cde = 2600
      AND src_due_dte >= 'TODAY'

    UNION ALL -- YTD Current Overdue Charges - Raised in the current year but PAST due
    SELECT src_bil_yer AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        0 AS bfw_arr,
        0 AS bfw_int,
        0 AS ytd_chg,
        src_trn_amt AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran
    WHERE src_trn_cde = 2600
      AND src_due_dte < 'TODAY'
)
GROUP BY
    bil_yer,
    acc_num,
    ubsgch_key_num
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned RDBMS you use but most RDBMS have a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). You can use it. You use `src_bil_yer + 1` in first subqueries and it is a `group by` field so you have to use nested query anyway. 
Try following query:

```
SELECT 
    bil_yer,
    acc_num,
    ubsgch_key_num,
    sum(bfw_arr) AS bfw_arr,
    sum(bfw_int) AS bfw_int,
    sum(ytd_chg) AS ytd_chg,
    sum(ytd_och) AS ytd_och
FROM (
    SELECT src_bil_yer + 1 AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        CASE WHEN src_trn_cde <> 2601 THEN src_trn_amt ELSE 0 END AS bfw_arr,
        CASE WHEN src_trn_cde = 2601 THEN src_trn_amt ELSE 0 END AS bfw_int,
        0 AS ytd_chg,
        0 AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT src_bil_yer AS bil_yer,
        src_acc_num AS acc_num,
        des_ubsgch_key_num AS ubsgch_key_num,
        0 AS bfw_arr,
        0 AS bfw_int,
        CASE WHEN src_due_dte >= 'TODAY' THEN src_trn_amt ELSE 0 END AS ytd_chg,
        CASE WHEN src_due_dte <  'TODAY' THEN src_trn_amt ELSE 0 END AS ytd_och
    FROM av_ub_tran
    WHERE src_trn_cde = 2600
)
GROUP BY
    bil_yer,
    acc_num,
    ubsgch_key_num
```